# OCaml Factorial Function with Restrictions

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to learn OCaml on my own, and I've reached imperative programming. I found this little exercise that I'm just completely stuck on how to even approach. It seems so simple, but I think my understanding is just lacking.

The problem asks me to write the function for factorial without using the rec keyword, and without loops. It's supposed to teach me the environment model, but that's also confusing to me.

My first thought was to try something like this:

```
   let factorial = 
       let f = ref (fun n -> 0) in  
       let temp_factorial n =
           if n = 0
               then 1
           else
               begin 
                   f := n * !f*(n-1)
                   !f
               end
```

But I'm not sure if this works. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why are you not sure if it works? It either works or it doesn't. Presumably it doesn't since you're here, so how do you know? Do you get an error message or an output that is not as expected. If so, it would be a good idea to add that to the question so we can see it too. See [ask] for more on asking good questions.

Comment: Obviously it doesn't work. Doesn't event compile due to unfinished `let` binding. Please, correct your compilation errors or if you can't, post here the error you don't understand and someone will explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little strange and wrong, but the basic idea is workable. Once you have a reference `f` to a function of type `int -> int`, you can use `!f` freely in later code. In fact you can assign `f` so it refers to a function that uses `!f`. This is equivalent to recursion, but it uses the imperative part of OCaml.

```
let f = ref (fun n -> n + 1)

f := 
    (fun n ->
    if n < 2 then 1
    else (* ... left as an exercise ... *)
    )

let factoral n = !f n
```

The key is that the part `left as an exercise` can use `!f`.